# Map Values from 2 column

Tags: r, mapping

I found that it's possible to map values in R in the following way (with package wrapr):

```
map <- qc( "word" = "newword")
```

I have a CSV file, lets name the dataframe df, with column a_xPlacexHolderxColumnaPlacexHolderx_, and b.
Is there a way to map the values from the entire data frame? Something like:

```
map <- qc( df$a = df$b)
```

When I try it, it says:

```
Error: unexpected '=' in " map <- qc( df$a ="
```

Comment: It seems you need to `Map`...so maybe something like `Map(function(x, y)qc(x = y), df$a, df$b)`

Comment: `setNames(df$b, df$a)`?